# document.write - javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to load resources based on the devices type (Mobile/desktop), I'm using a JS function to detect the type of device and document.write to write the  resources in the HTML. This code is in the `<head>` of the page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (!is_mobile()) {
        document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/blabla-poc/js/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>');
    }else{
        document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

But it writes `document.writeln('<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>');` in the code instead of `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that what you're saying can possibly be happening.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it the "proper" way, with `s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = '...'; document.documentElement.children[0].appendChild(s);`?

Comment: I assume he is looking for the propper way :D

Comment: @Pointy could you please explain why?

Comment: Because it just cannot happen. What makes you think it *is* happening? Look closely at what you wrote in your question.

Comment: I also tried using document.createElement as suggested above, but I get the same code in the output HTML as it has not been parsed.

Comment: I fail to see how either of those two writes could possibly convert bootstrap.min.js and a path into "js/messages.js".

Comment: I posted the wrong string, I edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

Split the tags into more strings to prevent browser to understand them incorrectly

```
document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt ... ></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Update:

- Broken: http://demo.chobits.ch/js/include/index.html
- Fixed: http://demo.chobits.ch/js/include/fixed.html

Comment: This is not necessary.

Comment: @Pointy Really? All major browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) will display "Broken code" in the demo above...

Comment: The only thing that's required is obscuring `</script>` which was already done in the code posted by the OP.